# Unir dois arquivos no python

Tags: python

Tenho duas listas no python e quero deixar estes dois arquivos em um só. Ou seja, tenho dois arquivos que contem uma coluna com 360 linhas e quero deixar em um unico arquivo (pois preciso fazer um gráfico de matriz) com duas colunas e 360 linhas. Como faço? Já tentei unir os dois como arranjo no numpy porem o que acontece é que ele inclui como mais linhas em vez de criar uma coluna do lado, ficando um arquivo de 720 linhas e não com duas colunas de 360 linhas. Alguem pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tente criar uma lista concatenando as duas

```
#criando as duas listas para exemplo
a=[x for x in range(360)]
b=[y for y in range(361,721)]

#criando a nova lista
uniao=[]

#juntando as duas
for z in range(360):
    uniao.append([a[z],b[z]])
```

Comment: Deu certo. obrigada!